# Javascript - Change image when click, and go back to the same image when the button is clicked again

Tags: javascript

I add background audio to my website

I just want to create a button with an icon, and when the user visiting the website clicks the button, the sound goes mute.

I already have this script, and it works very well.

But i want to change the image from the button, i have two icons, one for play, it only shows the icon if the music is playing, and another one for mute, it only shows the icon if the music is muted

I've a script here, but it only works one time, in other words, the icon dont go back to the last image when i click for the second time, the icon doesnt change.

My english is bad, but i hope you understand.

Thank you.

Script

```
function changeImage() {


        if (document.getElementById("play").src == "img/play.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("play").src = "img/pause.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("play").src = "img/pause.png";
        }


     }
```

HTML

```
<a  onclick="mute(); changeImage(this); " id="mute"><img src="img/play.png" id="play" /></a>
```

Comment: Second `"img/pause.png"` should be `"img/play.png"`

Comment: One good way to do it would be adding data attributes to img element : <img data-one="img/play.png" data-two="img/pause.png" src="img/play.png" class="one">; Check the class on click, change to approproate source and change class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing image src's is not very reliable, that's why you are facing an issue here. It's probably includes domain name and not only the path. Try more flexible approach using CSS classes:

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="mute(); changeImage(this)" id="mute">
    <img src="img/play.png" id="play" />
    <img src="img/pause.png" id="pause" />
</a>
```

**JS**

```
function changeImage(obj) {
    obj.classList.toggle('playing');
}
```

**CSS**

```
#mute #pause {
    display: none;
}
#mute.playing #pause {
    display: block;
}
#mute.playing #play {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XurUS/

Note on support. Is you need to support IE9 then you can't use classList API, and need to go with usual `if (obj.className == 'playing') {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you are confused on if condition. you should make it play if it is not play and vica versa. try this:

```
    if (document.getElementById("play").src == "img/play.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("play").src = "img/pause.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("play").src = "img/play.png";
    }
```

Comment: also you don't have to send **this** to the function since you are not using it and not defined it on function definition `onclick="mute(); changeImage(); "`

Comment: @user2744048 - does it still switch the first time?  If not then the issue is your test -- look in the debugger and see the actual value of `src`